# JQuery dropdown with MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a JQuery script on a link that adds and additional input field every time the user needs. It works fine when the code is for a standard dropdown box but I need the dropdown to be the same list pulled from the same table. Like this:

```
$sql2="SELECT lot, name FROM Products ORDER BY name ASC";
$result2=mysql_query($sql2); 

<select name="test[]" id="test">
<option value=""></option>
<? while($rows2=mysql_fetch_array($result2)) { ?>
<option value="<? echo $rows2['lot']; ?>"><? echo $rows2['name']; ?></option>
<? } ?></select>
```

This works fine in standard php but I cannot figure out how to have this added by the user when clicking the functioning "Add field" which refers to the following JQuery. How do I add php to this jquery script to modify it so that when the user needs another dropdown box the same one will appear, autopopulated from the table?

JQuery in head:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var MaxInputs       = 40; //maximum input boxes allowed
var InputsWrapper   = $("#InputsWrapper"); //Input boxes wrapper ID
var AddButton       = $("#AddMoreFileBox"); //Add button ID

var x = InputsWrapper.length; //initlal text box count
var FieldCount=1; //to keep track of text box added

$(AddButton).click(function (e)  //on add input button click
{
    if(x <= MaxInputs) //max input box allowed
    {
        FieldCount++; //text box added increment
        //how do I add input box here with php code?
        $(InputsWrapper).append('<div><input name="test[]" type="text"     id="test" type="text" class="field text large" value="test'+ FieldCount +'" maxlength="15" onClick="this.select();" /><input name="test2[]" type="text" id="test2" type="text" class="field text" value="test field 2" maxlength="15" /><a href="#" class="removeclass">&times;</a></div>');
        x++; //text box increment
    }
return false;
});

$("body").on("click",".removeclass", function(e){ //user click on remove text
    if( x > 1 ) {
            $(this).parent('div').remove(); //remove text box
            x--; //decrement textbox
    }
return false;
}) 

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the same dropdown box, you can just use $.clone();

http://api.jquery.com/clone/

That way you do not need to repopulate the dropdown box from the backend, and it saves a lot of time.

I came up with an example explaining how you can use $.clone - http://jsbin.com/rorowomi/2/

1. Keep the dropdowns in a container parent element (a `div` or `section`).
2. When you clone a dropdown, you can either clone a specific dropdown or the first (in my example I clone the first parent div element.) Then appeend it to the container parent element that I mentioned in step 1.
3. Just put the dropdown in a parent element (again, `div` or `section`, or anything) and clone that parent element. Inside the parent element is also the delete button for the dropdown.
4. For the delete button, assign a onClick handler, which you can use `$.parent()` and `$.remove()` which will delete the parent element, which deletes the dropdown.

Comment: That was a simple workaround! Is there any easy way to remove the clones as well like the original script had?

Comment: If you want to remove the same dropdown, I would suggest instead of cloning the dropdown, you clone a parent element that contains the dropdown and the delete button. When you assign the $.click() handler on the dropdown, you can reference the parent with $.parent() and call .remove(). Please see http://jsbin.com/rorowomi/2/

Comment: Perfect thank you! Only thing I need to fix is that the buttons submit the form but other clone/remove is working perfectly.

Comment: Make sure you either e.preventDefault() or return false;

Answer (score 0):

I would rely on ajax and here is how.

first set a click event to the add field to dynamically add input fields, here I'll show a select box. This reaches out to a file called `ajax.php` to generate the input

```
$("#addfield").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.post("ajax.php", function(data) {
        $("#InputsWrapper").append(data.content);
    }, "json");
});
```

Our `ajax.php` then builds the input to return to the form

```
<?php

    $html[] = '<select name="test[]" class="remove">';
    $html[] = '<option value=""></option>';

    while($rows2=mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
        $html[] = '<option value="'.$rows2['lot'].'">'.$rows2['name'].'</option>';
    } 

    $html[] = '</select>';

    $response["content"] = implode("\n", $html);
    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

This then appends to the form from the `click` event

To remove an input we use the `.remove` class we applied to the input in ajax.php

```
$(document).on("click", ".remove", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).remove();
});
```

If you want to limit the number of inputs I would use a `PHP` session in ajax.php
to track the number of inputs. Add 1 to the session when creating and -1 when removing.  Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm not too familiar with AJAX but am trying your code. Do I call script with the same href="#" id="addfield"? I'm trying it and it's not working - thing that might be why.